# G-invariants of a group algebra

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

> Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$, and let $G$ be a finite $p$-group. Let $k[G]$ denote the group algebra, where the definition of a group algebra is the one provided [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupAlgebra.html). Consider $V$ a finitely generated left-$k[G]$ module. Let $$V^G=\{v\in V| \text{for all }g\in G, gv=v \}$$
>   Show that $V^G\ne 0$.

First what I noticed is that $(\sum_{g\in G} g)v$ in an element $V^G$, but I can't prove that it  is non-zero.

I am also suggested to reduce this to the case $k=\mathbb F_p$ (which would clearly be enough to solve the problem), so I tried some reasonable $G$ stable subspaces, but nothing gives me the desired result.

Comment: Hint: First note that if you take this subspace for a normal subgroup $H$, then that is a $G$-invariant subspace. Now apply this to a normal subgroup of order $p$ and repeat.

Comment: Alternatively, you can show that a finite $p$-subgroup of $GL_n(k)$ (where $k$ has characteristic $p$) is conjugate to a subgroup of the upper triangular matrices with $1$s on the diagonal (first reduce to the case of $k$ being finite and then apply Sylow's theorems).

Comment: I am really sorry, but can you help me understand your first argument though? So far I only understand that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $W=HV$, then $G(W)=W$, but nothing further.

Comment: What do you mean by $W = HV$ or by $G(W)$? It is fairly straightforward to write up why $V^H$ is a $G$-invariant subspace when $H$ is normal.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that line. You are right, $V^H$ is indeed a $G$-invariant subspace, so I assume that you mean that one shows that $V^H\ne 0$. Now what do you mean by repeat from here?

Comment: Now $V^H$ is a $G/H$-module, so you can do induction on the order of the group.